# Is there a government department in the Netherlands regulating sex work?

Tags: netherlands, government, prostitution

Do the Netherlands have a government department that specializes in understanding and analyzing sex work, and is tasked with maximizing the legal rights, ethical conditions, and positive outcomes for all parties involved, similar to the departments of education, energy, food, and drugs?

Comment: I suspect it probably falls under whatever agency is responsible for workers rights generally, though maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There either is, or is not, such a department, that is a mater of fact, not opinion.

Answer (score 4):

The Netherlands has a more pragmatic approach towards sex work, in which the government tries to balance the protection of the rights of sex workers with the need to prevent exploitation and abuse.

The Dutch government has implemented a number of policies and regulations to ensure the safety and rights of sex workers, but does not have a specific department responsible for the regulation of sex work. Instead, various government agencies and organizations, such as the police, public health agencies, and local municipalities, are involved in the regulation and oversight of the sex industry. These organizations work together to ensure that sex workers have access to health services, and that they are protected from exploitation and abuse.

The central government of the Netherlands has a policy of toleration and regulation of prostitution, meaning that they allow it to take place but they regulate it, this has been seen as a way to reduce the harm associated with sex work, such as exploitation and trafficking. It has a number of organizations that specialize in the understanding and analysis of sex work, such as the [Prostitution Information Center](https://pic-amsterdam.com/), which provides information and support to sex workers and the general public, and the Dutch Union of Sex Workers, which represents the interests of sex workers.

Answer (score 1):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

### The [sex industry](http://www.lawfoundation.net.au/ljf/site/templates/grants/$file/legalFactsEnglish.pdf) is just another industrial sector

It is regulated just like any other business and it also has specific regulation - just like construction, mining, health, logistics etc - covering its peculiarities.

There is no specific government department , instead, regulation is split across the three tiers of government and usually different parts of each tier. None of these deals exclusively with the sex industry.

**Commonwealth**

- The Australian Tax Office deals with tax compliance
- The Australian Competition and Consumer Commission deals with consumer protection and monopolistic behaviour (the latter is not much of a problem in the sex industry)
- The Australian Federal Police deal with cross-border criminality like human trafficking
- The Australian Securities and Investments Commission deals with company regulation

**State**

- NSW Fair Trading deals with general business regulation
- Safe Work NSW deals with work health and safety. They have specific [guidelines](https://www.safework.nsw.gov.au/resource-library/other-services/health-and-safety-guidelines-for-sex-services-premises-in-nsw) for sex work addressing the particular risks; just like they do for [most industries](https://www.safework.nsw.gov.au/your-industry)
- NSW Police deal with criminality such as sexual servitude
- Revenue NSW deals with state taxes like land and payroll tax
- Planning NSW sets statewide guidelines on development including which zoning areas are suitable for brothels and which aren’t

**Local**

- Local government determines which zones (established by Planning NSW) go where in their area and dealing with development applications

These lists are not exhaustive.